# How to solve the integral $\int_{0}^{b\theta}\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{100\theta}{x}-\frac{50\theta^2}{x^2}}$ via density functions?

Tags: probability, integration

I am trying to find the integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{b\theta}\frac{1}{x} \exp \left({\frac{100\theta}{x}-\frac{50\theta^2}{x^2}} \right )dx
$$

where $b$ is a large number, and $\theta \in (0,\infty)$. I am trying to see if I can re-interpret this as a probability density function and match coefficients. However, the integral doesn't go to infinity, and so I am not sure how to make it look like a Gamma distribution (my first line of attack). Does anyone have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to attack this with density functions, i.e. what is the context behind the problem? Is this related to similar problems you have solved using density functions in the past?

Comment: Don't see a way to interpret this as a know PDF. But by using a change of variables $y = \frac{\theta}{x}$ you can write the integral on the  (simpler?) form $e^{50}\int_{1/b}^\infty \frac{1}{y} e^{-50(y-1)^2}{\rm d}y$.

Comment: Your integral does not really depend on $\theta$, but just on $b$. I bet this is probably the relevant fact.

Comment: Hi, thanks, you are right about it not depending on $\theta$. I guess I don't really have to solve the integral, I just need to show that $1$ divided by the integral exists. How can I show that the above integral exists? Thanks.

Comment: As for why the integral exits: the integrand $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,b\theta]$. The only point that can screw things up are $x=0$ where we have a singularity. Try to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$ which would imply that the singularity is removable making the integral finite.